# How to get documents from different collections in firebase and add them to a single List to return as Stream?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create an Attendance App, so I want to get the courses in which the students are registered. The Student's class looks something like this:

```
class Student {
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final String number;
  final String regNo;
  List<CourseIDAndInstructorID> courses;

  Student({this.name, this.email, this.number, this.regNo});
}
```

The `List` named courses contains the document-ID of the instructor whose course it is, and the document-ID of the course document.(As one student would obviously be taking classes from different instructors)

Now using these two fields, I want to get the documents of the courses, create an Object of the custom class `Course` and then add this object to a `List`, that would be returned so that it can be displayed on the GUI.

But I am getting this Exception, whereas I clearly have data in the object.

[The image of the Exception Message can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6wv5.png)

```
final CollectionReference _instructorCollection =
    Firestore.instance.collection('instructors');

final CollectionReference _studentCollection =
    Firestore.instance.collection('students');

Stream<List<Course>> _getStudentCourses() async* {
    List<Course> courseList;

    DocumentSnapshot stdDoc = await _studentCollection.document(uid).get();
    Student _student = new Student.fromSnapshot(stdDoc);

    if (_student.courses.length == 0) {
      return; //TODO add appropriate return type
    } else {
      int len = _student.courses.length;
      while (len != 0) {
        len--;
        DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await _instructorCollection
            .document(_student.courses[len].instructorUID)
            .collection('courses')
            .document(_student.courses[len].courseID)
            .get();
        print(snapshot.data);
        Course course = new Course.fromSnapshot(snapshot);
        courseList.add(course);
        yield courseList;
      }
    }
  }
```

Can someone tell me, what I'm doing wrong or how I can do this?
If something is missing from the context of the question, kindly tell me so that I can add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to create the List object instead of just a pointer.

```
List<Course> courseList = new List();
```

[source](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/List-class.html)

Comment: Thank you sooo much for pointing it out, it was a really stupid mistake. I spent so much time trying to figure this out, so I really appreciate it.